# Hiking Mount Fuji in the off season

Tags: japan, international-travel, hiking, tokyo, mount-fuji

There are plenty of guides on hiking mount Fuji, and how to get there in the summer (the "open" season, July- early September).

I have read and been told that although the routes are technically closed after mid-September, and highly advised against between November and June (due to snow and bad weather), they are still accessible/open "at your own risk." It's just that the huts/stations are closed, and the busses/trains don't run (so you need a car).

Has anyone had experience with this? Can you drive to the 5th station (of any of the routes)? Are the paths still open?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Several tour outfits run winter climbs (for example: http://www.fujimountainguides.com/off-season-two-day-mt-fuji-tour.html)

Note from the website that permits are not required and apparently huts are available (at least to the tour operator)

I'd also recommend filing this form with the local police, and emailing their contact information for more advice...
http://www.fujimountainguides.com/uploads/1/5/3/1/15315858/climbing_information_form.pdf